# How to adjust the length of the hat?

Tags: symbols

While using `\widehat{w}` and `\widehat{m}` inside the math environment the length of the hat is lesser in the first. How to fix this length? I do not want to use `\hat` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\wh}{\widehat}
\begin{document}
$\widehat{w}$ 
$\widehat{m}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which math font font do you use?

Comment: Just use `\hat`, there's no need for `\widehat` here.

Comment: When I saw the question title in *"Hot Network Questions"* and didn't notice the site icon at first, I was very confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a proposed alternative taking double-width on the standard `\hat` (the actual proportion can be changed to suit, by editing the `{2}` and `{.5}` to a different set of reciprocals).  EDITED to handle all math style sizes, using `scalerel`'s native stretching macros.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\wh[1]{\hstretch{2}{\hat{\hstretch{.5}{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\hat{w} \hat{m}$ too narrow

$\widehat{w}  \widehat{m}$ not uniform

$\wh{w} \wh{m},
\scriptstyle\wh{w} \wh{m},
\scriptscriptstyle\wh{w} \wh{m}
$ proposed
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This hat is no longer centrally aligned with the symbol, unlike \hat. Is there a simple fix for that?

Comment: @level1807 If I am seeing the same thing as you, it is a very subtle difference.  But if it bothers you, maybe this: `\newcommand\wh[1]{\hstretch{2}{\hat{\hstretch{.5}{#1\mkern1mu}}}\mkern-1mu}`, which has two `\mkern`s added (equal and opposite).  You can play with the number `1mu`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think this effect is minor, especially over letters with sharper tops, like "f" or "A". Here's a comparison https://imgur.com/fHdLdvd

Comment: @level1807 excellent example (I note also that your example is not the computer-modern font).  Ideally, the kern amount should be proportional to the height of the letter, though you might be able to get away with a fixed kern.

Comment: yeah, it's newtx. I'm surprised this problem even exists. mtpro2 is the only font I know that has decent hats and tildes.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to stretch only the hat, while fixing its center point? That would make this universal between italic and roman text. Right now, as far as I understand, the horizontal alignment of accents is encoded in the font, which is why applying `\hat` to `\hstretch{0.5}{#1}` instead of just `#1` ignores this alignment. I'm just guessing here though.

Comment: @level1807 I believe your interpretation is correct on why it doesn't automagically work with `\hstretch`

Answer (score 4):

An easy solution with the small `makebox` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makebox}

\begin{document}

$\widehat{\makebox*{$m$}{$ w $}}\,\widehat{m}$

 unless you prefer this:

$\widehat{w}\,\widehat{\makebox*{$ w $}{$m$}}$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously, the current math style needs to be manually imported into the argument of `\makebox*`.

Comment: I didn't think of checking this point, I must say. Is there a noticeable difference  between the hats widths in scriptstyle and scriptscripstyle?